# Saving mousepad on Debian Xfce through cmd with pid

Tags: debian, xfce

Ran into strange problem of having issue while on Debian's Xfce.

I have 3 window applications running:

1. Deluge
2. Firefox
3. Mousepad

(I forget if that's the order they appear in by default or not)

Now, I minimized the three and walked away from computer. Then I come back and wake up computer from screen saver. I move mouse towards the top bar to click to restore a window so I can view that window. However the 3 bars disappeared!

Here is what I mean by *3 bars* - this is example of what they look like

[3 bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb6BP.png)

This wasn't too much a problem for deluge and firefox as a simple restart I was OK with.

***Problem:*** I have **Mousepad** running with several important **unsaved** files (somewhat ironic in this day and age, heh). I have Task Manager PID of that same mousepad (1274 to be exact) and I was wondering how/can I save those files? Can I somehow save through command line with the pid? Or more simply can I restore the window to view it and save visually?

Cheers

Comment: I thought this question may be interesting, however I realized the workspace you're on is the last one... Could it be that you've simply moved to a different workspace and the original mousepad is running OK in the first (non-highlighted) workspace? E.g. from [this](http://cdn.xfce.org/about/screenshots/4.10-2.png) workspace, user is in the first of two workspaces as indicated by the top of the screen.

Comment: Nick thanks that was it! @Jamil that's what I was looking for (so marked as answer for the sole question I asked), but to my own stupidy it wasn't needed -.- cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen the xcfe4 panel misbehaving in certain computers when resuming from suspend, hibernation or even when the screen is turned off by the screensaver.

Generally, that happens because of a "crash" on the xcfe4 panel itself, your applications are probably running fine on the background, only their GUI representation have "disappeared". Try restarting the panel to see if the windows come back:

```
xfce4-panel -r
```

Also, you may try to launch a new instance of Mousepad -- if it opens, it would probably show the unsaved files there.